# Python - Unpacking a two index dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe, df, consisting of financial transactions over a period of time.   I have reindexed the df to the date of each transaction.

```
                 Description      Amount       Category
date      
2018-12-03       Stop & Shop      $100.00      Groceries
2018-12-03       Shell            $50.00       Gas
2018-12-02       NYC Parking      $25.00       Auto
2018-12-01       Tonys Pizza      $14.00       Dining
2018-11-30       Dr Jones         $100.00      Medical
```

I am attempting to group this data by month and expense category.   EG:

```
            Auto    Dining   Gas      Groceries    Medical
Dec-2018    $25.00  $14.00   $50.00   $100.00      $100.00
Nov-2018    $35.00  $72.00   $40.00   $125.00      $0.00 
 ...
Jan-2018
```

I attempted to achieve this by using 'groupby' and "Resample.agg" to accumulate transactions by Category and Month, but do not know how to manipulate the resulting dataframe "output" to display the output in the format I am hoping for.

```
output = df.groupby('Category').resample('M').agg({"Amount":'sum'})
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### [`pd.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) + [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`pd.Grouper`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.Grouper.html)

You can transform series values into column labels and *then* `groupby`:

```
df = pd.pivot_table(df, index=df.index, columns='Category', values='Amount')\
       .groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='M')).sum().fillna(0)

print(df)

Category    Auto  Dining   Gas  Groceries  Medical
2018-11-30   0.0     0.0   0.0        0.0    100.0
2018-12-31  25.0    14.0  50.0      100.0      0.0
```

#### [`pd.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html) + [`to_period`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html)

You can also perform the above operations via a cross-tabulation:

```
df = pd.crosstab(df.index.to_period('M'), columns=df['Category'],
                 values=df['Amount'], aggfunc='sum').fillna(0).rename_axis(None)

print(df)

Category  Auto  Dining   Gas  Groceries  Medical
2018-11    0.0     0.0   0.0        0.0    100.0
2018-12   25.0    14.0  50.0      100.0      0.0
```

**Setup**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Amount': [100.0, 50.0, 25.0, 14.0, 100.0],
                   'Category': ['Groceries', 'Gas', 'Auto', 'Dining', 'Medical'],
                   'Description': ['Stop&Shop', 'Shell', 'NYCParking', 'TonysPizza', 'DrJones']},
                  index=pd.to_datetime(['2018-12-03', '2018-12-03', '2018-12-02', '2018-12-01', '2018-11-30']))
```